# Building a native package using Maven

Tags: java, maven

After finally having enough of the hacky batch-based workflow for a project, I tried "porting" it to Maven. This is my first time using a build tool for Java, so there's probably a lot of room for improvement.

#### General setup

```
B:\WORKSPACE\COM.MSGPROGRAMS.AUDIRAS
│   .classpath
│   .project
│   icon.ico // icon used for the exe
│   LICENSE
│   LICENSE-mp3agic
│   pom.xml
│   README.md
│   RELEASE.txt
│   UPDATES.txt
│
├───.settings
│       // eclipse data
│
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │   └───com/msgprograms/audiras
│   │   │                       └─ // source, not relevant
│   │   │
│   │   └───resources
│   │           icon.png  // icon used for the tray icon
│   │           lang_deu.txt
│   │           lang_eng.txt
│   │           streams.txt
│   │
│   ├───packaging
│   │       jpack-appimg-args.txt
│   │       jpack-installer-args.txt
│   │
│   └───test
│       └─── // not relevant
│
└───target
    ├───appimg
    ├───appimg-work
    ├───installer-work
    ├───jar
    ├───packaging
    └─── // omitted standard dirs, these are the dirs that are used while creating the installer at some point
    Audiras-2.0.0.msi // installer to be uploaded somewhere
```

#### pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.msgprograms</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.msgprograms.audiras</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>

    <name>com.msgprograms.audiras</name>
    <url>https://github.com/msg-programs/Audiras</url>
    <description>Minimalistic internet radio recorder</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>16</java.version>

        <!-- properties for jpackage to read -->
        <appName>Audiras</appName>
        <appVendor>msg-programs</appVendor>
        <mainClass>com.msgprograms.audiras.RadioMain</mainClass>
        <winUpgradeUUID>d8cd072d-c607-44aa-b2aa-53bf096aba9a</winUpgradeUUID>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mpatric</groupId>
            <artifactId>mp3agic</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <!-- jpackage arg files. need to be filtered first -->
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/packaging</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/packaging</targetPath>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <!-- default resource dir needs to be re-added -->
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- output to directory. jpackage can't read singular files for input arg -->
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jar</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- don't install locally -->
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.github.wiverson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jtoolprovider-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <!-- first pass in package phase. -->
                    <!-- create the files that will be installed ("application image") -->
                    <!-- use appimg-work as temp, result goes into appimg -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jpack-appimg</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java-tool</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <toolName>jpackage</toolName>
                            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                            <args>@${project.build.directory}\packaging\jpack-appimg-args.txt</args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- second pass in install phase. -->
                        <!-- build an installer ("application package") -->
                        <!-- use installer-work as temp, result goes into the build dir -->
                        <id>jpack-installer</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java-tool</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <toolName>jpackage</toolName>
                            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                            <args>@${project.build.directory}\packaging\jpack-installer-args.txt</args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- copy licenses and other files into app image -->
                        <!-- run between package and install phase of jpackage -->
                        <id>copy-files</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <fileSets>
                                <fileSet>
                                    <sourceFile>${project.basedir}\LICENSE</sourceFile>
                                    <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}\appimg\${appName}\LICENSE.txt</destinationFile>
                            </fileSet>
                            <fileSet>
                                <sourceFile>${project.basedir}\LICENSE-mp3agic</sourceFile>
                                <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}\appimg\${appName}\LICENSE-mp3agic.txt</destinationFile>
                                </fileSet>
                                <fileSet>
                                    <sourceFile>${project.basedir}\RELEASE.txt</sourceFile>
                                    <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}\appimg\${appName}\RELEASE.txt</destinationFile>
                            </fileSet>
                            <fileSet>
                                <sourceFile>${project.basedir}\UPDATES.txt</sourceFile>
                                <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}\appimg\${appName}\UPDATES.txt</destinationFile>
                                </fileSet>
                            </fileSets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.github.wiverson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jtoolprovider-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.34</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

[jtoolprovider docs](https://github.com/wiverson/jtoolprovider-plugin). It's a straightforward way of running java tools such as jlink, jdeps or jpackage via Maven.

#### jpack-installer-args.txt

```
--type msi
--app-version ${project.version}
--copyright "(C) ${appVendor}"
--description "${project.description}"
--name ${appName}
--dest ${project.build.directory}
--temp ${project.build.directory}\installer-work
--vendor ${appVendor}
--app-image ${project.build.directory}\appimg\${appName}
--win-dir-chooser
--win-menu
--win-menu-group ${appVendor}
--win-upgrade-uuid ${winUpgradeUUID}
```

#### jpack-appimg-args.txt

```
--type app-image
--name ${appName}
--dest ${project.build.directory}\appimg
--temp ${project.build.directory}\appimg-work
--input ${project.build.directory}\jar
--icon ${project.basedir}\icon.ico
--main-jar ${project.build.directory}\jar\${project.build.finalName}.jar
--main-class ${mainClass}
```

#### Building the installer

1. Build the jar into target/jar (phase compile)
2. Use the jar to build an app image into target/appimg (phase package)
3. Move other files such as licenses and update infos into the app image (phase verify)
4. Use the app image to build an installer into target (phase install)

---

Any feedback is welcome, be it regarding Maven projects in general or my installer building in particular.